# Which is better for grinding coffee: Food processor or blender?

Tags: grinder

Which is better for grinding coffee for use in a drip coffee maker: Food processor or blender?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is better for grinding coffee: Food processor or blender?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/5023/which-is-better-for-grinding-coffee-food-processor-or-blender)